# White gridlines over image using JES (python)

Tags: python, line, draw, jython, jes

How can I write a program using JES to draw “White” gridlines on an image where the horizontal
gridlines are separated by 10 pixels and the vertical gridlines are separated
by 20 pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, surprisingly, `addLine(picture, startX, startY, endX, endY)` can only draw black lines !?

So let's do it by hand. Here is a very basic implementation:

```
def drawGrid(picture, color):

  w = getWidth(picture)
  h = getHeight(picture)

  printNow(str(w) + " x " + str(h))

  w_offset = 20  # Vertical lines offset
  h_offset = 10  # Horizontal lines offset

  # Starting at 1 to avoid drawing on the border
  for y in range(1, h):     
    for x in range(1, w):
      # Here is the trick: we draw only 
      # every offset (% = modulus operator)
      if (x % w_offset == 0) or (y % h_offset == 0):
        px = getPixel(picture, x, y)
        setColor(px, color)


file = pickAFile()
picture = makePicture(file) 
# Change the color here
color = makeColor(255, 255, 255) # This is white
drawGrid(picture, color)
show(picture)
```

***Note : this could also have been achieved a lot more efficiently using the function drawLine(), from the script given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17333395/1715716).***

Output:

---

.......[image].........[image].......

---