# def negatives in JES

Tags: jes

I am trying to show my picture as a negative, and I coded it, but it wont show the picture as a negative, did I do something wrong?

```
def negative(picButterfly2):
    for px in getPixels(picButterfly1):
        red=getRed(px)
        green=getGreen(px)
        blue=getBlue(px)
        negColor=makeColor(255-red, 255-green, 255-blue)
        setColor(px,negColor)
```

ALSO HOW DO I DRAW HORIZONTAL LINES? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with correct variables names: you have `picButterfly2` NOT EQUAL TO `picButterfly1`:

This works:

```
def negative(picButterfly1):
   for px in getPixels(picButterfly1):
      red=getRed(px)
      green=getGreen(px)
      blue=getBlue(px)
      negColor=makeColor(255-red, 255-green, 255-blue)
      setColor(px,negColor)

file = pickAFile()
picture = makePicture(file)

negative(picture)
show(picture)
```

Also look at:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17158026/1715716) (for negating images).
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16704548/1715716) (for drawing lines) - or any of [those](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjes%5D%20draw%20lines).

Answer (score 0):

Your variables "red", "blue", and "green" already have a function in it, change it to a single character or just a capital letter like "Red". I know this was posted in 2014 but I'll leave a comment for the future.